# Linq Any() side effects with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, refactoring

I am current refactoring some code that uses Entity Framework.

What I cannot really figure out is the reason why someone called `Entities.Any()`, it looks random but the comment says that it is used to override the lazy loaded values. It still make no sense to me as calling `Any()` should not modify the underlying collection.

Should I feel comfortable deleting this statement?

The code looks like this:

```
class MyEFObject {

    public virtual ICollection<Entity> Entities { get; set; }

    public void SetEntities(ICollection<Entity> entities)
    {
        // [...]

        Entities.Any(); // to override lazyloaded values
        Entities = entities.Where(a => a.MyEFObjectId == Id).ToList();

        // [...]
    }

 }
```

Of course there are no tests so I cannot verify what the intended behaviour is.

Comment: Take a look at this article https://www.tutorialspoint.com/entity_framework/entity_framework_lazy_loading.htm

Comment: `Entities` appears to be an in-memory collection, that's about to be replaced.  `Any()` would just check if there's at least one item in that collection (and then throw away the result).  I can't see it possibly having any effect.

Comment: I would not remove that code. The `Any` is not essential here (`GC.KeepAlive(Entities);` or similar fake method would have the same effect) - the essential is to invoke the `Entities` property *getter*.

Comment: @Ivan Stoev can you explain why would we want to invoke the Entities getter in this case?

Comment: If the object is tracked by the EF context change tracker, it's important to make sure the collection is loaded from the database (i.e. to get the original values) before replacing it. That allows EF to detect add/delete/update operations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Any()` will just check if there's one or more items in a collection which matches a given predicate. Without the predicate (as in your case) it will check if there's at least one item in the collection.

It won't change anything in your collection, however - that's what I think that coworker wanted to achieve - it forces the runtime to evaulate the expression to retrieve the values from the database. As you might know, expressions returning an `IEnumerable` or `IQueryable` are not executed as long it is not needed to do so. The first call to that expressions which depends on the return values of the expression will force its execution and your coworker might have seen that then the SQL profiler shows incoming statements.

However, I see that the line below calls a `ToList()` which also makes sure that the expression is executed immediately. So no, you really should not need that `Any()`.

Comment: I agree. I don't see any value in having it there.